# ¿Cómo obtener valor de elementos hijos de un nodo en documento XML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml, xpath

Para obtener el valor de un elemento en documento XML, escribo algo como esto:

```
XmlNodeList nodo = documentoXml.GetElementsByTagName("Fecha");
```

Esta me devuelve una lista de los elementos con el nombre especificado, y puedo acceder a sus valores mediante la posición que ocupan en la lista. Por ejemplo:

```
string Fecha = nodo[0].InnerXml;
```

Pero si el elemento tiene hijos como el elemento Detalle ¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener sus valores ? por ejemplo:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<FacturaElectronica xmlns="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Clave>50628031800310140886100100001010000000003145592145</Clave>
<NumeroConsecutivo>00100001010000000003</NumeroConsecutivo>
<FechaEmision>2018-03-28T08:00:24-04:00</FechaEmision>

-<Emisor>
 <Nombre>NEOTECNOLOGIAS SA</Nombre>
-<Identificacion>
  <Tipo>02</Tipo>
  <Numero>3101408861</Numero>
</Identificacion>
<NombreComercial>NEOTECNOLOGIAS SA</NombreComercial>

-<Ubicacion>
  <Provincia>1</Provincia>
  <Canton>02</Canton>
  <Distrito>01</Distrito>
 <Barrio>01</Barrio>
  <OtrasSenas>CENTRO CORPORATIVO PLAZA ROBLE EDIFICIO LAS TERRAZAS 5TO   PISO</OtrasSenas>
</Ubicacion>

-<Telefono>
  <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
  <NumTelefono>40701540</NumTelefono>
</Telefono>

-<Fax>
  <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
  <NumTelefono>40701540</NumTelefono>
</Fax>
 <CorreoElectronico>brojas@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
</Emisor>

-<Receptor>
 <Nombre>Dental Care</Nombre>
-<Identificacion>
  <Tipo>02</Tipo>
  <Numero>3001123208</Numero>
</Identificacion>

<NombreComercial>Dental Care</NombreComercial>

-<Ubicacion>
  <Provincia>1</Provincia>
  <Canton>01</Canton>
  <Distrito>01</Distrito>
  <Barrio>01</Barrio>
  <OtrasSenas>Amon</OtrasSenas>
</Ubicacion>

-<Telefono>
  <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais
  <NumTelefono>40701590</NumTelefono>
</Telefono>

-<Fax>
   <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
   <NumTelefono>40701590</NumTelefono>
</Fax>
   <CorreoElectronico>comprador@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
</Receptor>
    </FacturaElectronica>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener los valores de Numero y Referencia hijos del nodo Detalle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues basando a tu forma de trabajar, recuperas el nodo **Detalle**
y dentro de ella recuperas los nodos (que serian subnodos), y vas especificando cuales quieres recuperar.

Anexo un pequeño código, yo no soy tanto de C#, me quedé en VB, pero espero se entienda la idea.

```
private void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc;
        XmlNodeList nodo;
        XmlNode elemento;
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\file.xml");
        nodo = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Detalle");
        foreach (var elemento in nodo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemento.SelectSingleNode("numero").InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine(elemento.SelectSingleNode("referencia").InnerText);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si te animas a usar linq to xml podrias usar algo como esto

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string xml = @"<Factura> 
               <Fecha> 28/03/2018 </Fecha>
                <Detalle> 
                    <numero>423561</numero>
                    <referencia>vnb432432</referencia>
                </Detalle>
            </Factura>";

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var result = from factura in doc.Descendants("Factura")
            select new {
               Fecha = factura.Element("Fecha").Value,
               Detalle = new {
                 numero = factura.Element("Detalle").Element("numero").Value,
                 referencia = factura.Element("Detalle").Element("referencia").Value,
            }
        };

        foreach(var item in result){
            Console.WriteLine(item.Fecha);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Detalle.numero);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Detalle.referencia);
        }
    }
}
```

como veras es muy simple de trabajar los nodos y convertir esto a objetos

Answer (score 0):

Una forma  de obtener los valores de elementos de un documento XML es usando sintaxis XPATH, de esta forma se puede acceder directamente o de forma aleatoria segun su posicion dentro del documento...

Explico

por ejemplo si en el documento existen varios elementos llamados **Numero** y deseamos obtener el valor del segundo elemnto de este tipo hacemos lo siguiente:

```
public void ObtenerValorDeNodo(XmlDocument documentoXml)
        {
            string uri = "https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica";
            XmlNamespaceManager nS = new XmlNamespaceManager(documentoXml.NameTable);
            nS.AddNamespace("xs", uri);
            XmlNode  nodo = documentoXml.SelectSingleNode("(//xs:Numero)[2]", nS);
            string valorNumero = nodo.InnerText;
        }
```